# My COVID api does not appear to work all the time. How to prevent or fix this issue?

Tags: javascript, api

```
const axios = require('axios');
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

const { promisify } = require('util');
const setAsync = promisify(client.set).bind(client);

const baseURL = 'https://covidtracking.com/api/states/daily';

async function getDailyStates() {
  console.log('Retrieving the past 14 days of COVID data for each state');

  let statesData = {};
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(baseURL);

    for (let i = 0; i < 784; i++) {
      const currentState = data[i];
      if (!currentState.state) {
        console.log(currentState);
        continue;
      }
      if (statesData[currentState.state]) {
        statesData[currentState.state].push(currentState);
      } else {
        statesData[currentState.state] = [currentState];
      }
    }
    await setAsync('states-daily', JSON.stringify(statesData));
    console.log('Stored us daily into redis');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

getDailyStates();
// module.exports = getDailyStates;
```

I am working a on new project, and I am running into a wall. Sometimes, my code will return the correct information. Other times, it will error out and I can't figure this out for the life of me. Here I ran it 7 times and it passes 1 /7. Thank you for all your help and suggestions.

[image]

Comment: The server is rejecting your requests.

Comment: @GetSet do you know why? DucTran can you console.log(data)?

Answer (score 1):

Hit `F12` and check the network panel....that API takes > 65 seconds to send out the response (I'm on 50 MBit here). I think this is generally quite a crappy (or quite overcrowded) API, because it's just 1.1MB of JSON, which is likely being rendered live instead of being cached.

Check before accessing `data[i]`, in order to at least prevent it from throwing errors:

```
if(typeof(data[i]) !== 'undefined') {
    /* Access property in here.  */
} else {
   console.error('index ' + i + ' is absent.');
}
```

The original data-source might be: https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv
That's globally and not only the US, but the US CDC might have a similar feed available: https://data.cdc.gov/browse?q=covid&sortBy=relevance

Comment: Without load-balancer, it may also run out of ports, occasionally (when really crowded).

Comment: Which would be always since OP tests result in 1/7 returns

Comment: I am not convinced that there's an issue with the API. if you run the demo on my answer below, does it take a long time for you? for me it returns all the time after a 170ms for the first call, and less than 50 for the rest

Comment: I don't know... I watched it downloading and just wondered when it will complete...that might be routing-related (right now, 2.38MB/s in 5.5s with `wget`). Somewhere seems to be a bottleneck; so I tried to find other administrative resources. That the speed varies that much is not "normal" and the other sources should be behind load-balancers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-playground-forked-61z4y?file=/src/index.tsx)

Iterate over the returned object, e.g.

```
const { data } = await axios.get(baseURL);
data.forEach(element => {
  statesData[element.state] = statesData[element.state] || [];
  statesData[element.state].push(element);
});
```

Comment: I really like the `.forEach()` better, because I already wondered about the 784 before... which probably should be `data.length`. JS doesn't throw any `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: 784 is the total number of data point for all us states and territories for a two week period

Comment: @DucTran got you. I noticed that 'https://covidtracking.com/api/states/daily' redirects to 'https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/daily.json', and when I call this endpoint I get no errors. I changed the demo to use that hard limit of 784, check the demo and see if it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

The api is pretty slow sometimes and other times it is not slow. The server probably needs some improvement but that's the nature of using third party apis. Mostly if there's no token as it's probably getting hammered by a bunch of people.

I did see that the URL you are using is a redirect into the actual API endpoint so this is not helping with the slowness.

Here is the API endpoint you want to be using

```
 https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/daily.json
```

I saw that you are not checking dates but instead, you are assuming data is ordered. This is dangerous as you don't know what the server is doing when providing you the array of entries.
I updated your code to calculate the dates that you want and added some comments to help you understand the setup.

[Running Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/covid-tracking-xgsly?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) --> Look at the console to see the output data.
NOTE: I commented out the redis part as demo doesn't have a running redis. But I tested this locally on my setup that has redis and it works like a charm.

[image]

**CODE**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const redis = require('redis');
const moment = require('moment');

const client = redis.createClient();

const { promisify } = require('util');
const setAsync = promisify(client.set).bind(client);

const baseURL = 'https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/daily.json';

async function getDailyStates() {
  console.log('Retrieving the past 14 days of COVID data for each state');

  try {
    // Get current date
    const today = moment().format("YYYYMMDD");

    // Get last 14 days starting with yesterday to match with. 
    // We do this as we don't know when they publish todays data.
    // Make sure these are in number format to match json payload.
    const last14DaysArray = Array.from({ length: 14}, (_, index) => Number(moment(today).subtract(index + 1, 'days').format("YYYYMMDD")));
    
    const response = await axios.get(baseURL);

    if(!response || !Array.isArray(response.data) || !response.data.length) {
      throw new Error('Data was empty in response')
    }

    const { data } = response;

    let statesData = {};
    data.forEach((currentEntry) => {
      if(!last14DaysArray.includes(currentEntry.date) || !currentEntry.state) {
        return;
      }

      if (statesData[currentEntry.state]) {
        statesData[currentEntry.state].push(currentEntry);
      } else {
        statesData[currentEntry.state] = [currentEntry];
      }
    });

    await setAsync('states-daily', JSON.stringify(statesData));
    console.log('Stored us daily into redis');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

getDailyStates();
```

Also with third party apis make sure to keep an eye out on their up time. This server provides you this info through https://covidtrackingproject.statuspage.io/. That will help you know if future issues are from the server being down or your code.

Good luck!!